# LibGDX - TextButton wont work the second time

Tags: android, libgdx

I am currently working on a school project and i have encountered a bug i cant solve alone :/

I have 2 Screens: MainMenue and LoginScreen. Both Screens are in my ScreenMap (just a simple HashMap that contains all my screens)

If i touch the button "btnLogin" im coming to the LoginScreen(There is no Login-logic yet). Through the button "btnLogin" i go back to the MainMenue. Now the weird part is coming. Back in the Mainmenue i cant click on any button doesn't matter what i do. The button doesn't even get highlighted like normally and he just doesn't work.

MainMenue:

```
private int xSize;
private int ySize;
private long lastStarSpawnTime;
final Main game;
private Texture smallStar_Texture;
private Texture gameName_Texture;
private Texture playerShip_Texture;
private AssetLoader assetLoader;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Array<Rectangle> starBuffer;
private Rectangle gameNameRect;
private Rectangle startGameRect;
private Rectangle loginRect;
private Rectangle playerShipRect;
private Stage stage;
private TextButton btnStartGame;
private TextButton btnLogin;
// TODO Positionierung der Menueelemente nochmal anschauen
public MainMenueScreen(final Main gam) {
    game = gam;
    this.assetLoader = game.getAssetLoader();
    starBuffer = new Array<Rectangle>();
    xSize = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    ySize = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    loadAssets();
    initMenueElements();
    initStage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, xSize, ySize);
    game.screenMap.put("mainmenue", MainMenueScreen.this);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    game.batch.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < starBuffer.size; i++) {
        game.batch.draw(smallStar_Texture, starBuffer.get(i).x, starBuffer.get(i).y);
    }
    game.batch.draw(playerShip_Texture, playerShipRect.x, playerShipRect.y);
    game.batch.draw(gameName_Texture, gameNameRect.x, gameNameRect.y);
    game.batch.end();
    if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastStarSpawnTime > 10000000) {
        spawnStarSmall();
        spawnStarSmall();
        spawnStarSmall();
    }
    Iterator<Rectangle> iter = starBuffer.iterator();
    // StarAnimation Logic
    try {
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            Rectangle star = iter.next();
            star.y -= 1500 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            if (star.x < 0 || star.x > xSize) {
                iter.remove();
            }
            if (star.y + 2 < 0) {
                iter.remove();
            }
        }
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initStage() {
    stage = new Stage();
    Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"), assetLoader.getBtn_300x80_black_grey());
    //BtnStartGame
    btnStartGame = new TextButton("Start Game", skin);
    startGameRect = new Rectangle();
    startGameRect.height = btnStartGame.getHeight();
    startGameRect.width = btnStartGame.getWidth();
    startGameRect.x = (xSize / 2) - (startGameRect.width / 2);
    startGameRect.y = ySize - ((gameNameRect.height / 2 + 5) + 4 * (startGameRect.height / 2 + 50));
    btnStartGame.setPosition(startGameRect.x, startGameRect.y);
    btnStartGame.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, new quickmode_Level_02(game.getAssetLoader())));
            dispose();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(btnStartGame);
    //BtnLogin
    btnLogin = new TextButton("Login", skin);
    loginRect = new Rectangle();
    loginRect.height = btnLogin.getHeight();
    loginRect.width = btnLogin.getWidth();
    loginRect.x = (xSize /2) - (loginRect.getWidth() / 2);
    loginRect.y = ySize - ((loginRect.height / 2 + 5) + 4 * (loginRect.height / 2 + 100));

    btnLogin.setPosition(loginRect.x, loginRect.y);
    btnLogin.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new LoginScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(btnLogin);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
@Override
public void show() {
    //reInitListeners();
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}
@Override
public void pause() {
}
@Override
public void resume() {
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
}
private void loadAssets() {
    gameName_Texture = assetLoader.getMainMenue_GameName_Texture();
    smallStar_Texture = assetLoader.getMainMenue_Star_Small_Texture();
    playerShip_Texture = assetLoader.getPlayerShipTexture_normal();
}
private void spawnStarSmall() {
    Rectangle star = new Rectangle();
    star.x = MathUtils.random(0, xSize);
    star.y = MathUtils.random(ySize, ySize + 50);
    star.height = smallStar_Texture.getHeight();
    star.width = smallStar_Texture.getWidth();
    starBuffer.add(star);
    lastStarSpawnTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
}
private void initMenueElements() {
    //GameName
    gameNameRect = new Rectangle();
    gameNameRect.height = gameName_Texture.getHeight();
    gameNameRect.width = gameName_Texture.getWidth();
    gameNameRect.x = (xSize / 2) - (gameNameRect.width / 2);
    gameNameRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (gameNameRect.height / 2 + 100);
    //Playership
    playerShipRect = new Rectangle();
    playerShipRect.width = playerShip_Texture.getWidth();
    playerShipRect.height = playerShip_Texture.getHeight();
    playerShipRect.x = xSize / 2;
    playerShipRect.y = 0 + playerShip_Texture.getHeight() + 50;
}
private void reInitListeners() {
    btnLogin.clearListeners();
    btnStartGame.clearListeners();
    btnLogin.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new LoginScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    });
    btnStartGame.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game, new quickmode_Level_02(game.getAssetLoader())));
            dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

LoginScreen:

```
 final Main game;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
//Textures
private Texture username_Texture;
private Texture password_Texture;
private Texture gameName_Texture;
private AssetLoader assetLoader;
private Rectangle gameNameRect;
private Rectangle usernameRect;
private Rectangle loginRect;
private Rectangle newaccountRect;
private Rectangle passwordRect;
private Rectangle usernametxfRect;
private int xSize;
private int ySize;
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
private TextButton btnLogin;
private TextButton btnNewAccount;
private TextField txfUsername;
private TextField txfPassword;
public LoginScreen(final Main game) {
    this.game = game;
    this.assetLoader = game.getAssetLoader();
    xSize = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    ySize = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    loadAssets();
    initLoginMenue();
    initStage();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, xSize, ySize);
    game.screenMap.put("loginscreen", LoginScreen.this);
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.0f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    game.batch.begin();
    //Draw
    game.batch.draw(gameName_Texture, gameNameRect.x, gameNameRect.y);
    game.batch.draw(username_Texture, usernameRect.x, usernameRect.y);
    game.batch.draw(password_Texture, passwordRect.x, passwordRect.y);
    game.batch.end();
}

private void initLoginMenue() {
    //GameName
    gameNameRect = new Rectangle();
    gameNameRect.height = gameName_Texture.getHeight();
    gameNameRect.width = gameName_Texture.getWidth();
    gameNameRect.x = (xSize / 2) - (gameNameRect.width / 2);
    gameNameRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (gameNameRect.height / 2 + 100);
    //username
    usernameRect = new Rectangle();
    usernameRect.height = username_Texture.getHeight();
    usernameRect.width = username_Texture.getWidth();
    usernameRect.x = (xSize / 4) - (usernameRect.width / 2);
    usernameRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (usernameRect.height / 2 + 300);
    //password
    passwordRect = new Rectangle();
    passwordRect.height = username_Texture.getHeight();
    passwordRect.width = username_Texture.getWidth();
    passwordRect.x = (xSize / 4) - (passwordRect.width / 2);
    passwordRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (passwordRect.height / 2 + 430);
    //loginButton
    btnLogin = new TextButton("Login", skin);
    loginRect = new Rectangle();
    loginRect.height = btnLogin.getHeight();
    loginRect.width = btnLogin.getWidth();
    loginRect.x = (xSize / 3) - (loginRect.width / 2);
    loginRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (loginRect.height / 2 + 580);
    //newAccountButton
    btnNewAccount = new TextButton("New Account", skin);
    newaccountRect = new Rectangle();
    newaccountRect.height = btnNewAccount.getHeight();
    newaccountRect.width = btnNewAccount.getWidth();
    newaccountRect.x = (xSize / 3 * 2) - (newaccountRect.width / 2);
    newaccountRect.y = ySize - 1.5f * (newaccountRect.height / 2 + 580);
    //usernameTextfield
    txfUsername = new TextField("Klick mich!", skin);
    usernametxfRect = new Rectangle();
    usernametxfRect.height = 300;
    usernametxfRect.width = 80;
    usernametxfRect.x = usernameRect.x;
    usernametxfRect.y = usernameRect.y + 300;
}

private void loadAssets() {
    username_Texture = assetLoader.getLoginScreen_username_Texture();
    password_Texture = assetLoader.getLoginScreen_password_Texture();
    gameName_Texture = assetLoader.getMainMenue_GameName_Texture();
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"), assetLoader.getBtn_300x80_black_grey());
}

private void initStage() {
    stage = new Stage();

    //BtnLogin
    btnLogin.setPosition(loginRect.x, loginRect.y);

    btnLogin.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {

            game.setScreen(game.screenMap.get("mainmenue"));
            //dispose();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(btnLogin);
    //BtnNewAccount
    btnNewAccount.setPosition(newaccountRect.x, newaccountRect.y);
    btnNewAccount.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            game.setScreen(new NewAccountScreen(game));
            dispose();
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(btnNewAccount);
    //txfUsername
    txfUsername.setPosition(usernametxfRect.x, usernametxfRect.y);
    txfUsername.setWidth(usernametxfRect.getWidth());
    txfUsername.setHeight(usernametxfRect.getHeight());
    stage.addActor(txfUsername);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
}
@Override
public void show() {
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}
@Override
public void pause() {
}
@Override
public void resume() {
}
@Override
public void dispose() {
}
```

Comment: The reInitListeners(...) in Main looks like an unusual approach. What if you take that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the `Stage` is not your `InputProcessor` anymore.
This is, because as soon as you call `new LoginScreen()` you call `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);`, which replaces the current `InputProcessor` (the `stage` in `MainMenue`) with the new one (the `stage` in `LoginScreen`).
If you then switch back to the `MenuScreen`, ``Gdx.input.setInputProcessor` is never called.

The solution:
Set the `InputProcessor` inside the `show()` method, or maybe even better, call `initStage()` inside the `show()` method and reset `stage` (set it to `null`) inside the `hide()` method, to release the ressources.
To let you know: If you call `setScreen(newScreen)` for your game, `oldScreen.hide()` and tehn `newScreen.show()` gets called.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks that was the solution i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you leave your screen and come back to it, it's not the input processor anymore and won't be because you're using the same old screen you used before. You are setting your input processor in the constructor of your screens (Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);). When I switch screens I do it like so:

```
game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen());
```

If you make a new instance, your constructor will get called (which is where you are setting your input processor). Making a new instance might seem wasteful, but I've never experienced any lag from it. Conversely, if you're keeping all your screens in a map they are all taking up some amount of heap space throughout the life of your program (though probably not much). I would just ditch the map and instantiate screens as needed.